# socket file description

Tags: c, linux, sockets

So I totally lost it when someone showed me some code using select() like:

```
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(socket,&readfds);
FD_SET(0,&readfds);
.......// bind() and listen(),regular stuff
// Before select(),this guy cleared readfds to null and sort of start all over again
FD_ZERO(&readfds);// Behold,this is exactly the line confusing myself
FD_SET(socket,&readfds);
// select will be called in the future within a infinite loop
```

So basically saying what `FD_ZERO` after bind and listen is clear previous contents for some reason and insert socket file descriptor to fd set again.Meanwhile,in fd set,the 0 descriptor(standard input) apparently disappeared.

Could anyone explain this whole thing? I don't feel like this is correct but i cant really figure it out. Maybe setting up some specific fd set all over again is a practical mechanism...

I thought `bind()` and `listen()` could modify fd set in some sort of manner.I set up a couple of breaking points and examine the outputs.Consequently,fd set did not change at all.

**UPDATE:**

What really confuses me is the second `FD_ZERO(&readfds)`.
Obviously the first one is like clearing rusty stuff in the buffer. On each iteration,we have to clear fdset to default for the future. I just dont understand the second one. Either it is a wrong one or it wont hurt at any rate.

Comment: `select` will change the fdset, but `bind` and `listen` can't, they aren't even given a pointer to it.  But do yourself a favor and use a modern API like `poll` or `epoll` and don't worry about fdset ever again.

Comment: sounds cool but i just cant get it over

Comment: Use `poll`. It's modern and portable and fast. `epoll` is only for benchmark self-pleasuring and the benchmarks it excels in do not correspond to most real-world use needs (where `epoll` is actually much slower than `poll`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where your confusion lies, but here's an explanation.

An fdset is a bitmask of file descriptors indexed from zero (technically, I don't think it *has* to be a bitmask but any other implementation would be ... strange).

So an fdset may be something like:

```
              Byte 0                              Byte 1
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|fd0|fd1|fd2|fd3|fd4|fd5|fd6|fd7| |fd8|fd9|fd10|fd11|fd12|fd13|fd14|fd15|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

The idea is that you set the bit for a given fd (file descriptor) if you're interested in it. If you're not interested in it, you leave the bit clear.

`FD_ZERO` will clear all bits, which is a good starting point. Then the two `FD_SET` calls will set the bits for `fd0` (standard input)  and `fd<socket>`.

Then, a select call using that fdset would return if either there was action on standard input or action on the socket (the *type* of action would depend on which parameter position you used when passing the fdset to `select`. Passing it as the read fdset means that you'll return if either you can read the socket or something has shown up on standard input (such as you using the keyboard).

This may well be the useful in the code for a "chat" application since it would wait on input from either you or your friend at the other end.

The reason why you have to re-zero and re-set the bits in an fdset is because `select` itself modifies the set to indicate what fd (or fds) it detected the action on.

Example: if something came in via the socket and nothing via standard input, the fdset would be modified by `select` to only have that bit set. That way you can use `FD_ISSET` to detect which fds you should look at.

---

If, as you seem to indicate in comments, there are *no* `select` calls (or other calls using `readfds`) between the two `FD_ZERO()/FD_SET()` sequences then, yes, it appears that the first is unnecessary, since the information will be overwritten by the second.

Without seeing the full code, or the architectural design documents :-) , it's hard to tell.

Comment: what confuses me is the code actually clear &readfds itself twice.

Comment: @y26jin, it's because `select` modifies the array - I've added to the answer to expand on that.

Comment: i mean,the second one was called before select() modifying anything.

Comment: if nothing from std input and sth through socket,when select() stops blocking and returns,socket bit is discarded and stdinput bit is still around,is that correct?

Comment: @y26jin: Not quite, other way around. Any bit where there is _no_ action is cleared. Only bits that have action are left set.

Comment: In the Windows WinSock implementation of `select()`, the `fd_set` type is _not_ a bitmask, so it's not as strange as we might think.  See: [MSDN fd_set structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737873(v=vs.85).aspx)  The `FD_*` macros hide the implementation, so the same code will work under both Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`Select()` is used when you are trying to listen over multiple sockets at the same time. Every time you 'accept()` a socket connection a socket descriptor is returned and you use this to send/receive files.

When you do a `FD_SET` you add a socket descriptor to the set (it may be read/write). `FD_ZERO` clears all entries from that particular set.

So essentially everytime you accept a connection you can add the socket descriptor to the set (that is if you want to use that socket to read/write).

When you call the `select()` function you specify the set you want to use. (Eg: readfds) and the `select()` polls all the sockets which are already in that set (readfds).

For more clarification read [beej's guide to network programing](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Its a very good tutorial to learn.

Answer (score 0):

[`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) modifies its argument fd sets, so you are supposed to re-initialize them on each iteration.